# Creating polygons from linestrings that has some duplicate line?

Tags: python, matplotlib, polygon, shapely

below code shows how input data look like.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import MultiLineString
from math import sqrt
import random 

GM = (sqrt(5)-1.0)/2.0
W = 8.0
H = W*GM
SIZE = (W, H)
dim = (1400,2500)
def plot_data(lines,center):
    fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=SIZE, dpi=90)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
    mline1 = MultiLineString(lines)
    plot_coords(ax, mline1)
    plot_lines(ax, mline1)        
    for i in range(len(center)):
         ax.plot(center[i][0],center[i][1],'or')
         ax.annotate("P%d"%i,(center[i][0],center[i][1]))
    ax.set_title('General Polygon')
    xrange = [-1, float(dim[0])]
    yrange = [-1, float(dim[1])]
    ax.set_xlim(*xrange)
    ax.set_ylim(*yrange)
    ax.set_aspect(1)        
    plt.show()

def v_color(ob):
    r = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
    hex_number = '#%02X%02X%02X' % (r(),r(),r())
    return hex_number

def plot_coords(ax, ob):
    for line in ob:
        x, y = line.xy
        ax.plot(x, y, 'o', color='#999999', zorder=1)

def plot_lines(ax, ob):

    for line in ob:
        x, y = line.xy
        ax.plot(x, y, color=v_color(ob), alpha=0.7, linewidth=3, solid_capstyle='round', zorder=2)        


linestring = [[(1071.0, 2.0), (1197.0, 2.0), (1197.0, 475.0), (1071.0, 475.0), (1071.0, 2.0)], [(945.0, 2.0), (945.0, 475.0), (1071.0, 475.0), (1071.0, 2.0), (945.0, 2.0)], [(1052.0, 475.0), (1218.0, 475.0), (1218.0, 981.0), (1052.0, 981.0), (1052.0, 475.0)], [(945.0, 475.0), (945.0, 1210.5), (1052.0, 1210.5), (1052.0, 475.0), (945.0, 475.0)], [(1052.0, 981.0), (1208.0, 981.0), (1208.0, 1192.0), (1052.0, 1192.0)], [(1062.0, 1192.0), (1062.0, 1665.0), (1062.0, 1210.5), (945.0, 1210.5), (945.0, 2235.5), (1062.0, 2235.5), (1062.0, 1665.0), (1188.0, 1665.0), (1188.0, 1192.0), (1062.0, 1192.0)], [(1062.0, 2021.0), (1218.0, 2021.0), (1218.0, 2232.0), (1062.0, 2232.0), (1062.0, 2021.0), (1198.0, 2021.0), (1198.0, 1665.0), (1188.0, 1665.0)], [(1132.5, 2235.5), (352.0, 2235.5), (352.0, 2321.5), (1132.5, 2321.5), (1132.5, 2235.5)], [(1132.5, 2321.5), (1132.5, 2407.5), (352.0, 2407.5), (352.0, 2321.5), (1132.5, 2321.5)], [(825.0, 2108.0), (352.0, 2108.0), (352.0, 2234.0), (825.0, 2234.0), (825.0, 2108.0)], [(352.0, 2096.0), (352.0, 2391.0), (2.0, 2391.0), (2.0, 2096.0), (352.0, 2096.0)], [(386.0, 2.0), (386.0, 2108.0), (945.0, 2108.0), (945.0, 2.0), (386.0, 2.0)], [(386.0, 2096.0), (2.0, 2096.0), (2.0, 2.0), (386.0, 2.0), (386.0, 2096.0)]]
center = [(1135.0, 728.0), (1140.0, 2126.5), (1130.0, 1086.5), (1130.0, 1843.0), (1134.0, 238.5), (1125.0, 1428.5), (742.25, 2278.5), (742.25, 2364.5), (1008.0, 238.5), (1003.5, 1723.0), (998.5, 842.75), (665.5, 1055.0), (588.5, 2171.0), (194.0, 1049.0), (177.0, 2243.5)]

plot_data(linestring,center)
```

Data include many linestrings, some of them has duplicate lines. i wanna combine lines to create rectangles(or polygons).
There are 2 problems that i dont know how to merge these lines to create a big shape and then create polygons from this shape.

Comment: I ran your code and it seems to work fine. Could you edit your question and clarify what exactly the problem is? It would help if you showed the expected output and how it is different from what you are getting right now.

Comment: Edited my problem, i hope you could understand it

Comment: Still not clear. Do you simply want to make a Polygon from each inner list of `linestring`? Like `polygons = [Polygon(x) for x in linestring]`? I'm also not sure what you mean by "*big shape*"

Comment: That was my old way in the past but some linestrings dont have same format (like use combine 2 linestrings to create 2 polygons)  i could  if i use this method i will get result like this: 
https://ibb.co/HdBs0sc
Look at the right up corner (P6, P7), so i have to change method